# Outlook, VBA macro, Connection string to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, vba, outlook, connection-string, adodb

I am new in VBA via Outlook, so ...

I use Outlook 2016, and SQL Server 2017, and I try to connect a macro to SQL Server Express 2017 via ADODB.

Here is my code

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim cnnStr As String
    
    cnnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
             "Server=ALTROISIEME\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
             "Initial Catalog=XX_Options;" & _
             "Trusted_Connection=SSPI;" & _
             "uid=xxxx;" & _
             "pwd=xxxxxx;"
    
    'GoTo Fin_99
    
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900
    cnn.ConnectionString = cnnStr
    cnn.Open
    
    GoTo Fin_99
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "USP_Outlook_Add_File_Data"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Categorie", adVarWChar, adParamInput, , "IB_DailyTrade")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@NomDuFichier", adVarWChar, adParamInput, , FileNameExt)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Donnee", adVarWChar, adParamInput, , HTMLTxt)
    
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rst.Open cmd
    
    Set rst = cmd.Execute

ExitNewItem:
    GoTo Fin_99
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem

Fin_99:

On Error GoTo CloseRst
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing

CloseRst:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
```

The macro throws an error on line

```
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Cnn
```

with a message.

> 91-Variable object or variable of block not defined

Could you help?

Thank you
André

Comment: The version I use, I put the "Goto Fin_99" in comment.

Comment: I just figure my error, I should add a SET instruction after the following 
Dim cnn as New ADODB.connection
Set cnn = new ADODB.Connection                  <----new line

Dim Cmd as ADODB.Command
Set cmd = new ADODB.Command                   <----new line

Dim rst as new ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = new ADODB.Recordset                   <----new line


Now I have an error in the parameters definition

Comment: If you've got past the first problem that your question was about, you should probably update it with the new error details that you're seeing

Comment: One quick thing to note (which could be your problem) - I don't believe need to include the @ symbol in the parameter name.  So, in the case of your example, it would just be "Categorie", "NomDuFichier", "Donnee"

Comment: Does `USP_Outlook_Add_File_Data` return a set of results?  If No, you don't need a recordset here.

Comment: Putting blocks of code in comments is mostly unreadable. Please edit your question to show the current state of your code and the full text of error message(s) you are receiving. It's not clear whether you've fixed `Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command` or not. And you don't seem to be specifying length values in your CreateParameter() calls.

Answer (score 0):

I found all my issues. The code is not so far from my initial post:

```vb
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim cnnStr As String
    
    cnnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
             "Server=?????????\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
             "Initial Catalog=???????;" & _
             "Trusted_Connection=SSPI;" & _
             "uid=???;" & _
             "pwd=???;"
      
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900
    cnn.ConnectionString = cnnStr
    cnn.Open
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "USP_Outlook_Add_File_Data"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Categorie", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, "IB_DailyTrade")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@NomDuFichier", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, FileNameExt)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Donnee", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, HTMLTxt)
    
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rst.Open cmd
    
    Set rst = cmd.Execute

ExitNewItem:
    GoTo Fin_99
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem

Fin_99:

    If cnn.State = 1 Then
       cnn.Close
       Set cnn = Nothing
    End If
    
    If rst.State = 1 Then
       rst.Close
       Set rst = Nothing
    End If
```